# Toggle between images on a particular row when clicked on images on that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here what i am trying to ask is, i have used the “tabledit” jquery plugin for table specifications. Hence i am adding “images” through “tabledit” “html:” keyword, like below code i am adding "images". [screen shot of my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBysB.png)

```js
$('#projectsTable').Tabledit({

           url: '#',
           deleteButton: false,
            


         buttons: {
               edit: {
                   class: 'btn btn-primary secodary',
                   html: '<img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png" id="edit" /><img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_ok.png" id="ok" style="display:none" />',
                   action: 'edit'
              }

           },

           columns: {
               identifier: [1, 'Projects'],
               hideIdentifier: true,
             editable: [[1, 'Projects'], [2, 'Subprojects'],[8, 'Project Status', '{"1": "Open", "2": "Closed"}']]
           },



           onDraw: function() {
               console.log('onDraw()');
           },
           onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               console.log('onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)');
               console.log(data);
               console.log(textStatus);
               console.log(jqXHR);
           },
           onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
               console.log(jqXHR);
               console.log(textStatus);
               console.log(errorThrown);
           },
           onAlways: function() {
               console.log('onAlways()');
           },
            onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
                console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
                console.log(action);
                console.log(serialize);
            }
   


      });
```

but here i want toggle between “edit” and “ok” images on particular row when i clicked on that row button. But as i implemented it only toggle between images in first row of my table, this code is not applicable for remaining rows images. So can anyone tell me how can i implement this code to every row of my table. [result of my java script function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMcxp.png) ,the code what i tried is

```
var toggle = true;
function changing() 
{
document.getElementById("edit").style.display = toggle ? 'none' : 'block';
document.getElementById("ok").style.display = toggle ? 'block' : 'none';
toggle = !toggle; 
}
```

Anyone please suggest me how to toggle between images on particular row images clicked.

Comment: Partial code and images? I could help you but'll it'll be generic, so you'll need the wherewithal to fill in the gaps yourself. Otherwise you could post a [mcve] and get better help.

Comment: okay i will post whole code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is applying it on element with `id = edit`, which is not what you  want. The function is applying for the 1st matching element you get back from `document.getElementById('edit')`, in your case just the first row.

you can try this way [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
//this assumes you have jquery. can also be acheived via vanilla js as well.
//listen to click event on the .edit and .ok (classes) buttons
// also good idea to increase accuracy by img.edit and img.ok instead of just matching on classes
$(function(){
    $('.edit').on('click',function(){   
       $(this).toggle();  
       //show the ok button which is just next to the edit button
       $(this).next(".ok").toggle();  
    });

    $('.ok').on('click',function(){ 
       $(this).toggle();  
       $(this).prev(".edit").toggle();     
    });
})
```

a even better approach

In the `table` edit action html just update like so

```
html: '<img class="edit" />',
```

css

```
.edit {
 background: url("/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

.ok {
background: url("/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_ok.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

script

```
$(function(){
    $('.edit').on('click',function(){   
         $(this).toggleClass( "ok" );          
    });
})
```

Comment: this code not showing "ok.png" when i click on the "edit.png", but it works for every row.

Comment: @praveen i've updated the answer. I see what you were trying to do. Let us know.

Comment: No probs. @praveen i've added a different approach which uses a single button instead of 2 different.

Comment: sorry, updated answer to include html. Just need a single image element with edit class on it. it will keep toggling.

Comment: check the url reference on the background image. i think it needs to be relative to the dir.